# Word to describe not liking adornments and "frills", liking simple "things"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that describes a person that does not like to dress things up, whether it be people, ideas, objects. Almost the idea "simple man" but as an adjective?

Comment: Most frequently, we'd say he's "*a **simple** man*", but "*a **no-frills*** kind of guy*" is also common and clear. Maybe synonyms for "*simple*" or "*basic*" are what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider *[spartan](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spartan)*

> often not capitalized :  marked by simplicity, frugality, or avoidance of luxury and comfort *a Spartan room*  [*Merriam-Webster*]

Also possible are *austere*, *abstemious*, and *ascetic*.

> *[austere](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/austere)*: severely simple or plain; *an austere design*
>
> *[abstemious](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/abstemious)*: moderate or sparing, esp in the consumption of alcohol or food; temperate
>
> *[ascetic](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ascetic)*: a person who practises great self-denial and austerities and abstains from worldly comforts and pleasures, esp for religious reasons

[*Collins*]

Comment: Oh, austere! Topical.

Comment: I don't think that you'd use spartan to describe a person.

Comment: @Okoning How about *He led a spartan lifestyle*?

Comment: Yes, that would work - but OP wanted a word to describe a person directly.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of **[modest](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/modest)** (Dictionary.com) fits well:

> 1) having or showing a moderate or humble estimate of one's merits, importance, etc.; free from vanity, egotism, boastfulness, or great pretensions.
>   2) free from ostentation or showy extravagance: *a modest house.*

Answer (score 0):

[Earthy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/earthy)

> practical and straightforward : open and direct

[Unpretentious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/unpretentious)

> free from any intent to deceive or impress others

[Folksy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/folksy)

> having or showing an unpretentious informality

And then, well, "simple," as you say. Simple would be the popular way to put it.

Answer (score 0):

Down-to-earth:

> - Not pretentious or affected; straightforward.
> - Not overly ornate; simple in style.

Basic:

> - elementary or simple.

Source:http://www.thefreedictionary.com/down-to-earth
Source:http://www.thefreedictionary.com/basic